# Exponentially Modified Gaussian_fitting_python

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, curve-fitting, least-squares

I've been trying to fit an EMG function to some data, which I know beforehand that they behave in such a way.
Here is the data
http://www.filedropper.com/data_12

My script so far is this:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy.fft.fftpack as F  
import math
from scipy import optimize
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit,leastsq
from scipy.special import erf

t,i=np.loadtxt('data.txt',unpack=True)


def EMG(x,a,b,c,d):
    '''. a = Gaussian heigth, b = location parameter (Gaussian center),
    c = Gaussian width, d = distortion parameter (a.k.a. modification factor or time constant).
    '''
    return [a*c*np.sqrt(2*np.pi)]/(2*d) * np.exp[(c**2/(2*d**2))-(x-b)/d] * [(d/np.abs(d))+np.erf[((x-b)/np.sqrt(2)*d)] -(c/np/sqrt(2)*d)]


errfunc = lambda p, x, y: (EMG(x, *p) - y)**2
guess=[1,512,1,0.5]
#optim, success = optimize.leastsq(errfunc3, guess, args=(t,i))
print leastsq(errfunc,guess[:], args=(t, i))
#Note the args argument, which is necessary in order to pass the data to the function.
```

The error I get is this:

" line 25, in EMG
    return [a*c*np.sqrt(2*np.pi)]/(2*d) * np.exp[(c**2/(2*d**2))-(x-b)/d] * [(d/np.abs(d))+np.erf[((x-b)/np.sqrt(2)*d)] -(c/np/sqrt(2)*d)]

TypeError: 'numpy.ufunc' object has no attribute '**getitem**' "

Could someone please help me fix this?
Thank you very much!

Comment: You appear to be using square brackets instread of parentheses (e.g. `np.exp[(c2/(2*d2))-(x-b)/d]`).  That won't work--Python treats that as indexing the object `exp`, which gives you the error that you see.  `exp` is a `numpy.ufunc`, and indexing it results in a call to the object's `__getitem__` method (which `exp` doesn't have).

Comment: Hello Warren! Thank you very much for your input. 
I replaced the brackets but now Python is complaining about the erf function. 

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'erf'

Comment: Hello,

I would like to fit the same curve to this dataset

http://www.filedropper.com/emgdata

but the result is a curve whose maximum value is much lower than the max value of the data.

 I have used the  steps from this thread  

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36900920/fitting-an-exponential-modified-gaussian-curve-to-data-with-python

I get some warnings

RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp

and 

 RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply

Is there a way I could improve my fit and get rid of these warnings?

Thanks

Comment: Did you solve this issue eventually?

Comment: Hi. No it's still deep low in the to do list.

Comment: You could look at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.exponnorm.html